# Need to delete and then insert in SQL table using merge

Tags: sql, merge

I have a condition where I need to use **MERGE**. 
If we have a matched record then we need to first delete the thing and then insert it. Can you guide me on how to do it. Here is my query, but I am getting an error

```
> An action of type 'INSERT' is not allowed in the 'WHEN MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement.
```

Which I agree is correct. Please help me to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
MERGE EntryInvoiceReference targetTable
  USING(
  Select * from @InvoiceReference inr join @HeaderInvoice_Temp hit
  on inr.[EntryInvoice_Id]=hit.InvoiceId
  ) sourceTable

  on targetTable.[EntryInvoice_Id]=sourceTable.Invoice_Id_Created
  WHEN MATCHED
  THEN DELETE
  WHEN MATCHED 
  THEN INSERT (
  [EntryInvoice_Id]
      ,[CIReferenceType]
      ,[CIReferenceValue]
  )
  VALUES(
  sourceTable.Invoice_Id_Created,
  sourceTable.[CIReferenceType],
  sourceTable.[CIReferenceValue]
  )
  WHEN NOT MATCHED 
  THEN INSERT (
  [EntryInvoice_Id]
      ,[CIReferenceType]
      ,[CIReferenceValue]
  )
  VALUES(
  sourceTable.Invoice_Id_Created,
  sourceTable.[CIReferenceType],
  sourceTable.[CIReferenceValue]
  );
```

Comment: *" If we have a matched record then we need to first delete the thing and then insert it."* - but why? Why don't just update matched record in the way you need?

Comment: actually I have one to many relation ship. At that time update is throwing error. and I dont have any other column to differentiate

Comment: If you must delete and insert, then do 2 separate statements in a transation. You **cannot** do this with MERGE

Comment: hmmmm... ok let see.. Thanks

Comment: @AnirudhAgarwal It looks like merge is not a suitable tool in your scenario. Use transaction and separate insert/delete statements